# How can I fit a bounding (semi-)ellipsoid to a cluster of 3D data points?

Tags: matlab, ellipse, least-squares, model-fitting, robust

I have a dataset of 3D points, which are arranged in clusters resembling a (semi-)ellipsoidal shape. When I try standard ellipsoid fitting as, e.g. implemented in the MATLAB function http://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/fileexchange/24693-ellipsoid-fit , I get imaginary radii, no matter if I apply the fitting to all points within the ellipsoidic volume or only to points sitting on its convex hull.

I wonder whether the fact that the cluster shape is more semi-ellipsoidal than resembling a full ellipsoid leads to these instabilities? Is there any more robust method that could solve my problem?

UPDATE:

This is an example for one such cluster of 3D points. The blue circles indicated points located on the convex hull of the cluster.

[image: Example for one cluster, blue circles indicate points located on the convex hull.]

The minimal working example for the convex hull case would be as follows:

```
k = convhull(x, y, z);
ind = unique(k(:));
[center,radii,evecs,~] = ellipsoid_fit([x(ind),y(ind),z(ind)], 1);
```

Comment: Can you show us how does your data looks like and a MWE?

Comment: Sure can, original question will be updated in a minute.

Comment: While preparing the working example, I seem to have found out that one source of error probably was the scaling (my data have much larger values for x- and y-axis)... Stupid! Still, the semi-ellipsoid aspect of the question remains open.

Comment: So you still get imaginary radii?

Comment: Not as often anymore. However, there are still cases where negative radii occur.

Comment: So, whats your question?

Comment: Mainly: How to estimate a SEMI-ellipsoid. But as a side-question also: How can I further robustify the estimation process, so that instead of 4% of all cases, 0% lead to imaginary radii.